# SQLite German special chars

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, collation, system.data.sqlite

Some German words contain the "ß" character.

However, sometimes people write "ss" instead and vice versa.
While not perfectly legal, this is a common practice.

For example, some people for example write "außer", and some write "ausser".

I would like to handle this nicely in my SQLite DB.

Therefore I have created a custom LATIN_NOCASE collation, but it does not work as expected:

I have inserted a word named "außer", and I would like to be able to find it when I search for "s" or "ss".

However, my selection returns no results.

Does anybody see where I went wrong?
Is a comparision as below enough or do I need to do something additional special?

Thank you.

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Globalization

<SQLiteFunction(FuncType:=FunctionType.Collation, Name:="LATIN_NOCASE")> _
Public Class SQLiteCaseInsensitiveCollation
    Inherits SQLiteFunction

    Private Shared ReadOnly _cultureInfo As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")

    Public Overrides Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer
        Return String.Compare(x, y, _cultureInfo, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(GetType(SQLiteCaseInsensitiveCollation))

        Dim c As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data source=:memory:")
        c.Open()

        Using nCmd As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = c.CreateCommand
            With nCmd
                .CommandText = "CREATE TABLE foo (word TEXT COLLATE LATIN_NOCASE)"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        End Using

        Using nCmd As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = c.CreateCommand
            With nCmd
                .CommandText = "CREATE INDEX 'idx_foo_word' ON 'foo' (word COLLATE LATIN_NOCASE)"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        End Using

        Using nCmd As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = c.CreateCommand
            With nCmd
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO foo (word) VALUES ('außer')"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        End Using

        Using nCmdSel As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = c.CreateCommand
            With nCmdSel
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE word LIKE '%ss%' COLLATE LATIN_NOCASE"

                Using r As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = .ExecuteReader
                    Do While r.Read
                        MsgBox(r("word"))
                    Loop
                End Using
            End With
        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm not sure at all if SQLite supports/uses the collation with `LIKE` expressions. Might want to check that out. - And, under no common circumstances would "ß" be transscripted to "s" in German anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culture `de-DE` does not ignore the differences between ss and ß.

You have to modify the strings yourself before doing the comparison.